# Copy command in Mac Terminal fails with "No such file or directory"

Tags: macos, terminal, cp

This should be straightforward, but I'm getting weird results.

I have a folder with subfolders containing ~4000 files.  I'm trying to copy just the files of a certain filetype to another folder, while preserving the subfolder hierarchy.

Command:

`cp -R /Users/Steve/Desktop/Hardscapes/*.LOB /Users/Steve/Desktop/Temp`

fails with the message:

`"/Users/Steve/Desktop/Hardscapes/*.LOB: No such file or directory"`.

I created the command by typing `cp -R` then dragging the source folder to the terminal window, adding `*.LOB` after the `/`, and dragging the destination folder to the terminal window.

Troubleshooting:

1. replacing `*.LOB` with `*.*` gives the same error.
2. `cp -R /Users/Steve/Desktop/Hardscapes/ /Users/Steve/Desktop/Temp` copies the entire `Hardscapes` folder to `Temp`, with all its subfolders and files.

Thanks for your help and suggestions.

**EDIT:** The folder `Hardscapes` contains only other folders.  If I run the command above using one of those folders as the source, the contents are copied faithfully.  The folder `Hardscapes` itself contains no `.LOB` files - they're only in the subfolders.

So maybe that's the issue, `cp` can't find any files corresponding to `Hardscapes/*.LOB`? But I thought the `-R` switch was supposed to tell it to look through all the subfolders.

Next I put a file named `Test.LOB` in the `Hardscapes` folder.  The command above copies *only* that file and none of the subfolders.  It looks like the `-R` switch is not doing its job.  Do I have the syntax right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`rsync -a --prune-empty-dirs --include '*/' --include '*.LOB' --exclude '*' /Users/Steve/Desktop/Hardscapes/ /Users/Steve/Desktop/Temp`

As you already mentioned, directory `Hardscapes` itself contains no `.LOB` files. That's why your mask `/Users/Steve/Desktop/Hardscapes/*.LOB` results in matching no files at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  The command did nothing at first, then I read the man page (I know, I know) and ran it again with -av flags and then again with -avv for *really* verbose.  That gave me about a trillion lines but at the end, it said:

delta-transmission disabled for local transfer or --whole-file
total: matches=0  hash_hits=0  false_alarms=0 data=0

I finally noticed in the output that it wasn't "showing" any .LOB files, and I removed the space in '*. LOB'.  That did it.

Many, many thanks for your help.

Comment: Oh, right, there was a space there. I've just fixed it. Great you were able to figure it out, since - as you said - `rsync` is not verbose at all without options.